# About bean of hasErrors

Tags: grails, gsp

Assuming i have the following object in my controller

```
objCollection = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

And in each obj is the following

```
obj1 = [
    input = value, inputA1 = valueA1, inputA2 = valueA2
]    

obj2 = [
    input = value, inputB2 = valueB2, inputA3 = valueA3
]

obj3 = [
    input = value, inputC2 = valueC2, inputA3 = valueA3
]
```

And my GSP looks something like this

```
<div class="control-group ${hasErrors(bean: objCollection.obj, field: 'input', 'error')}">
    <g:textField name='input' value='${objCollection?.obj}'>
</div>

<div id="subForm" class="subContainer">
    <g:each var='obj' in='${objCollection}' status='a'> 
        <div id='obj${a+1}'>
            <div class='subaccordion'>
                <div>
                    <g:each var='objInstance' in='${obj}' status="b">
                        <g:render template="miniForm" model="[b:b, objInstance:objInstance]"/>
                    </g:each>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:each>
</div>
```

While for the template miniForm

```
<div class="control-group ${hasErrors(bean: objInstance, field: 'input', 'error')}">
    <g:textField name='input' value='${objInstance?.obj}'>
</div>
<div class="control-group ${hasErrors(bean: objInstance, field: 'input', 'error')}">
    <g:textField name='input' value='${objInstance?.obj}'>
</div>
```

Where the name attribute is changed using jquery to input A1, A2, B1, B2, C1 and C3 upon form load.

Now my question is, did i passed the object properly to the bean on hasErrors? Because i tried to get the hasErrors to work but somehow it didn't work to my expectation.

Did i made any mistake anywhere?

Also did i map the object correctly to every input in GSP? I'm not quite sure on how to use the safe operator '?' to avoid nullPointer error.

Comment: One question per question :)

Comment: Owh sorry. If only one question, then it would be about passing the object to the hasErrors bean.